# Filtering file list and removing unwanted extensions using Enumerable and Lambda

Tags: c#, performance, lambda, ienumerable

I am using this code

```
       private IEnumerable<String> FindAccessableFiles(string path, string file_pattern, bool recurse)
    {
        IEnumerable<String> emptyList = new string[0];

        if (File.Exists(path))
            return new string[] { path };

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            return emptyList;

        var top_directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        // Enumerate the files just in the top directory.
        var files = top_directory.EnumerateFiles(file_pattern);
        var filesLength = files.Count();
        var filesList = Enumerable
                  .Range(0, filesLength)
                  .Select(i =>
                  {
                      string filename = null;
                      try
                      {
                          var file = files.ElementAt(i);
                          filename = file.FullName;                              
                      }
                      catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                      {
                      }
                      catch (InvalidOperationException)
                      {
                          // ran out of entries
                      }
                      return filename;
                  })
                  .Where(i => null != i);

        if (!recurse)
            return filesList;

        var dirs = top_directory.EnumerateDirectories("*");
        var dirsLength = dirs.Count();
        var dirsList = Enumerable
            .Range(0, dirsLength)
            .SelectMany(i =>
            {
                string dirname = null;
                try
                {
                    var dir = dirs.ElementAt(i);
                    dirname = dir.FullName;
                    return FindAccessableFiles(dirname, file_pattern, recurse);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // ran out of entries
                }

                return emptyList;
            });
        return Enumerable.Concat(filesList, dirsList);
    }
```

I've been hitting some performance problems iterating over folder that have 100k+ files in them - all images that I ignore when I enumerate over them.

I'm trying to work out how to exclude them from the enumerated list so they are never processed in the first place but can't work out how to do it.

I have a `List<String>` of extension I want to exclude and do this in the code using `Contains`.

Would I get a performance gain if I excluded them from `FindAccessableFiles` in the first place and how would I do it ? MY initial attempt was the throw an exception if the file extension was contained in the extensions list but I'm sure this isn't the best way.

The purpose of `FindAccessableFiles` is to produce a list of files that circumvented the problems of `GetFiles()` throwing an exception trying to access a file that threw a permissions error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with JaredPar, you want to make sure you don't re-enumerate.  Your returns should have a .ToList(), but also `var files = top_directory.EnumerateFiles(file_pattern);` needs it as well.

Exception handling is expensive, so adding more than what you have is not advisable.  Enumerate files doesn't support the kind of filtering you are looking for, so you'll end up having to do it manually somewhere, probably best to do this:

```
filename = excludedExtensionList.Any(e => e == file.Extension) ? null : file.FullName;
```

If you still have performance issues, you have to look at ways you might be able to break down the operation into smaller chunks: if the file names are reliable, you might be able to come up with a scheme to alter your EnumerateFiles pattern (all files starting with "a", then "b", then "c", etc).  Or if there's a lot of junk sitting all in the same folder, can the directory structures be changed such that the unwanted files are always in a subfolder you know to ignore?

Comment: Thanks for that - excluding the extensions from the list seems to work well.

Comment: Just as an update: We stopped the previous scan at 22 hours and it was 75% the way through a folder with 100k images in it. I added both suggestions above and the great suggestion from @JaredPar and the test scan against the same folder is down to 32 seconds. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that `FindAccessableFiles` is returning an `IEnumerable<string>` instance which will re-walk the entire directory structure every time it is enumerated.  The `Select` and `Where` clauses are re-evaluated every time the enumeration is walked and hence you are repeating this expensive work many times over.  One quick fix for this is to force the walking one time by calling `.ToList` on the returned value

```
return Enumerable.Concat(filesList, dirsList).ToList();
```

Note that this will cause the entire enumeration to be walked promptly at this point.  However it will be done only once.

If you are still seeing perf problems there are some other options you should consider

- You mentioned there are images you ignore.  I would filter them out before hitting the disk to get info about them.  Hitting the disk is much more expensive that say examining the path name
- Move the disk walking to a background thread

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. Had to give the answer to @Peter due to the exclusion code.